# sending multiple files in a single fax

Tags: java, file, fax

I have global api for Sending fax as shown in below code,currently i am able to send fax just single file as attachments, but i have another case of sending multiple files in a single fax request and files names are in this sequence as available in database

Here is Complete Code for Sending fax

```
package oracle.apps.print;

import com.softlinx.replixfax.*;
import javax.xml.ws.*;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.io.File;

public class Fax {

public String Fax(String Filepath,String faxno,String flg) {

        try {


            ReplixFaxService service = new ReplixFaxService();
            ReplixFaxPort port = service.getReplixFaxPort();
            ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "user");
            if (flg.toString().equals("N")) {           
                ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,"https://api.rpxfax.com/softlinx/replixfax/wsapi");
        } else {    
                ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,"https://api.rpxtest.com:8083/softlinx/replixfax/wsapi");
        }   


            Authentication auth = new Authentication();
            auth.setLogin("user");
            String password="pwd";

            auth.setPassword(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(password.getBytes()));
            auth.setRealm("MTBC");
            auth.setPasswordSecurity("base64");


            SendFaxInput sendFaxInput = new SendFaxInput();
            sendFaxInput.setAuthentication(auth);

            FaxRecipient recipient = new FaxRecipient();
            recipient.setFaxNumber(faxno.toString());

            Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
            File f = new File(Filepath.toString());
            attachment.setFileName(f.getName());

            Path path = Paths.get(Filepath.toString());
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            attachment.setAttachmentContent(data);

            sendFaxInput.getFaxRecipient().add(recipient);
            sendFaxInput.getAttachment().add(attachment);

        SendFaxOutput result = port.sendFax(sendFaxInput);
            System.out.println("Status Code= " + result.getRequestStatus().getStatusCode());

        if(result.getFaxInfo() != null){
             System.out.println("Fax ID = " + result.getFaxInfo().get(0).getFaxId());

            }
        return result.getRequestStatus().getStatusCode();
    //return "a";



        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        return ex.getMessage();

        }   
    }
 }
```

I am attaching file at

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
File f = new File(Filepath.toString());
attachment.setFileName(f.getName());

Path path = Paths.get(Filepath.toString());
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
attachment.setAttachmentContent(data);

sendFaxInput.getFaxRecipient().add(recipient);
sendFaxInput.getAttachment().add(attachment);
```

Can i parse my Above Files string to multiple attachments manner , 
need help to consider all files as attachments

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by myself adding the code for help

```
String[] f_paths = Filepath.split("///");
            for (int i = 0; i < f_paths.length; i++) {

                Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                File f = new File(f_paths[i].toString());
                attachment.setFileName(f.getName());

                Path path = Paths.get(f_paths[i].toString());
                byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
                attachment.setAttachmentContent(data);
                sendFaxInput.getAttachment().add(attachment);
            }
```

Just Split the Files String by separator and iterate via loop